# Como muestro una imagen que proviene de sql con blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

Tengo este código:

```
@code{

    public class imagenes
    {

        public string imgSrc { get; set; }



        public void carga()
        {
            string imagepath = @"D:\Test\13.jpg";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] byData = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(byData, 0, byData.Length);


            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byData);

            imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);

        }



    }

    <img src="@imgSrc" alt="imagen" />

}
```

cuya intención es mostrar una imagen desde la bd, es decir como arreglo de bytes pero no me deja agragarle el dato al src del img . Alguien sabe como hacer tal cosa?

Comment: La imagen no viene de SQL Server u otra base de datos, la pregunta esta mal formulada.

Answer (score 1):

Veo que esta pregunta lleva aquí más de dos meses pero, como observo que hay un error grave en tu código, te la respondo por si aún lo necesitas:

El elemento img debe de ir fuera del bloque @code, ya que este es solo para código en C#.

```
<img src="@imgSrc" alt="imagen" />

@code {
    ...
}
```